# MySQL COALESCE Function failing to return non null value

Tags: mysql

I have this very simply MySQL query:

```
SELECT m.REF_DATA_ID, COALESCE(m.SQL_FUNCTION, m.PHP_FUNCTION ) AS FUNCTION FROM AAB_REFERENCE_DATA_MANAGER m;
```

which returns the below data:

```
REF_DATA_ID | FUNCTION
88295       |
88296       |
88297       |
88298       | now()
88299       |
88300       | now()
88301       |
```

COALESCE() does not seem to be functioning properly in my query for some reason, when I run the below query:

```
SELECT m.REF_DATA_ID, m.SQL_FUNCTION, m.PHP_FUNCTION FROM AAB_REFERENCE_DATA_MANAGER m;
```

returns:

```
REF_DATA_ID  SQL_FUNCTION  PHP_FUNCTION
88295       |             |
88296       |             |
88297       |             |
88298       | now()       |
88299       |             | get_session_user_id
88300       | now()       |
88301       |             | get_session_user_id
```

I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong with COALESCE here...

The output I'm looking for is:

```
REF_DATA_ID  FUNCTION
88295       |        
88296       |        
88297       |        
88298       | now()  
88299       | get_session_user_id
88300       | now()
88301       | get_session_user_id
```

Comment: What is the data in function column in the source - empty string or NULL?

Comment: looks like you might have it. Thanks Shree - I believe it is an empty string... going to run an update query and see if that does it.

Comment: Emptystring is different with null values. And yes, `Coalesce` return emptystring.

Comment: Ok - Yep that did it. Shree if you post that as an answer I'll accept it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A blank string is not `NULL` (except in Oracle).  So, be more explicit with the comparison:

```
SELECT m.REF_DATA_ID,
       (CASE WHEN m.SQL_FUNCTION IS NULL OR
                  TRIM(m.SQL_FUNCTION) = ''
             THEN m.PHP_FUNCTION
             ELSE m.SQL_FUNCTION
        END) AS FUNCTION
FROM AAB_REFERENCE_DATA_MANAGER m;
```

Comment: "(except in Oracle)" - which is my usual playground. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: Thanks for the help and, while this worked I tend to be of the mindset to repair data and make it actually null add opposed to writing logic to account for broken reference data. After all I might tend to agree that an empty string is not a null value.

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT m.REF_DATA_ID, 
          COALESCE(If(Length(m.SQL_FUNCTION)=0, NULL, m.SQL_FUNCTION),
                   If(Length(m.PHP_FUNCTION)=0, NULL, m.PHP_FUNCTION)) AS FUNCTION
   FROM AAB_REFERENCE_DATA_MANAGER m;
```